# collectionView: reloadData works, reloadItemsAtIndexPaths does not

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` whose source data changes sometimes when offscreen. To update it when it returns, I wrote in the `CollectionViewController`:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.collectionView!.reloadData()
}
```

...and that works, but I never need to update more than one or two cells in my `UICollectionView`, so I thought it'd be better if I replaced the above version with:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.collectionView!.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(myArrayOfIndexPaths)
}
```

...but when I do, Xcode gives me an error saying:

> Operand of postfix '!' should have optional type, delete '!'".

When I delete the '!', it says that `UICollectionView` doesn't have a member named `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths`.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show the version of the code with `reloadItems`

Comment: Are you using a UICollectionViewController, or a UIViewController with a collection view in it? If the latter, how are you declaring "collectionView"?

Comment: @David - I edited my question to show my attempt with `.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths`
@rdelmar - I'm using a UICollectionViewController
thanks!

Comment: How do you create `myArrayOfIndexPaths`?

Comment: I do not get any error when I use you code (replacing myArrayOfIndexPaths with [NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)]). Did you add an outlet for the collection view (or are you using the outlet you get with the collection view controller)? Sometimes Swift errors are not very good; try replacing myArrayOfIndexPaths with what I had, and see if that silences the error.

Comment: @rdelmar - I didn't connect my viewController correctly as noted by Valentin below (and I think you are suggesting as well).  Thanks for the help!

Comment: You shouldn't have had to connect the collection view at all if you're using a UICollectionViewController -- it has an outlet to its collection view by default.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From your code it looks like you have declared your collectionView as Optional (with ?) at the end and maybe linked it to your storyboard using an @IBOutlet. To fix your issue you should remove the ? from the :

`@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView?`

and substitute it with:

`@IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!`

this way you are telling the compiler that your collectionView definitely exists (because you have linked it from your storyboard).

Alternatively, you can bind your collectionView by doing this:

```
if let collectionView = collectionView {
    collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(myArrayOfIndexPaths)
}
```

Comment: That's it -- thanks!  I appreciate the explanation and thanks for answering the questions of a complete novice!

Answer (score 6):

**Swift 4** reload all items in section

```
 override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    var indexPaths: [NSIndexPath] = []
    for i in 0..<collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) {
        indexPaths.append(NSIndexPath(item: i, section: 0))
    }
    collectionView?.reloadItems(at: indexPaths as [IndexPath])
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 3 version code**

```
var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
indexPaths.append(indexPath) //"indexPath" ideally get when tap didSelectItemAt or through long press gesture recogniser.
collectionView.reloadItems(at: indexPaths)
```

Comment: where do i get those indexPaths from please? Strictly Swift 3 please.

Comment: @nyxee I hope following code help you to understand it.

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
          indexPaths.append(indexPath)
}

Comment: I understand the code. the problem is that reloadData() is not updating my indexPaths even if my dataSource hase been populated. this means i cannot access the values at higher indices (from the server) but i can only access the sample data I enter manually before downloading server data.

Comment: @nyxee Sorry for late reply I was busy with workload. I need to understand your scenario in details if you still not resolve the problem please write here in detail so I can contribute my effort to resolve your issue. Thanks

Comment: this answer doesn't help... please add more details in the answer, where to write your code? the bigger context

Answer (score 1):

as a beginner i didn't know that there's a diference when you implement a collectionView as a direct child from another viewController and implement it as an embedded view inside a viewController, maybe some dev is facing the same problem and they doesn't know, if so, look for the correct approach :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload for single cell, you can specify the specific of the cell like this :-

```
for index in indexPaths {
            if index == [0, 0] {
                print(index)
                self.collectionView?.reloadItems(at: [index])
            }
        }
```

Hope this helps.